# Windows 10 desktop Bluetooth headset not recognized as such

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones, wireless-headset

I am having a problem with connecting a wireless headset (LG-HBS-FN6) to a Windows 10 desktop via bluetooth.

The machine I am trying to connect is running without a problem a different Bluetooth headset and has no trouble connection to a media center as Bluetooth and recognize both as audio devices.

However, for the problematic headset, it does see it as a Bluetooth device and connects to it, but does not recognize it as an audio device and is refusing to use it as an audio output (image below).

[image: Headset not detected as]

I have had in the past no trouble using the problematic headset with mobile devices (eg iPhone 11).

As debugging steps, I have trying connecting them while all the other Bluetooth devices are turned off, including the phone it is paired to, but to no avail.

The manufacturer's website does not seem to have any drivers available for the model - even the app to update the firmware does not support the headset to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

Fix Bluetooth problems in Windows 10
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-10-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c

Restared bluetooth service and paired the device again

Answer (score 1):

Seeing LG-HBS-FN6_LE tells that the pairing has failed, or the incorrect device was chosen. How to recover:

1. Remove the _LE device pairing from Windows
2. Stop and restart Bluetooth
3. To set the headset in pairing mode press the Pairing -button with the case open for for 3-5 seconds until the blue indicator LED blinks
4. Pair them again with Windows Bluetooth settings

The headset should pair and show up correctly as LG-HBS-FN6

Comment: Someone flagged your question for low quality, and it popped up in review. Please check [how to answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand why. As far as I can see your answer is correct so I just re-worded it to fit better the site. I had to edit rather heavily - please check I didn't leave anything out. I'd suggest taking the short [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how Q&A sites like this differ from internet forums. I'd also recommend checking the Asking and Answering sections in [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to see how things work.

Answer (score 0):

The User Manual for the LG HBS-FN6 says that the earbuds have to be in the charging case and you press the pairing button on the side until the charging case flashes blue.  It will then show up as a Bluetooth audio device on the BT windows settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).